# Required reading on the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, big-list, collatz-conjecture

I am currently writing a paper on 3x+1 and realized that despite having enough knowledge to work on a singular facet of the problem I lack a more broad understanding of the problem.  I have seen the thorough annotated bibliographies by Jeffrey C. Lagarias but I do not have the time to read most of them and I imagine plenty of them would not teach me much about the problem itself, even if I did take the time to dissect them.  So what are the papers people feel I should read with my limited time to gain the best possible understanding of the Collatz Conjecture?

Comment: Perhaps the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) would be a good starting place?

Comment: I don't understand asking for an annotated bibliography from us when you already have access to one by THE expert. By the way, do you know that Lagarias has published a book on the problem? Maybe that's the first thing to look at.

Comment: I meant one of significantly shorter length but I will remove that part of the post anyways to avoid confusion.  No I did not know, any chance you could post a link to it I could not seem to find it via google.  Thank you for your helpful comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's challenging to distill a required reading on the Collatz conjecture, because it's unsolved. What may or may not be necessary? As you might have noticed from Lagarias's annotated bibliographies, there is a lot of literature on the subject, and it seems as though Lagarias has already sifted through a whole lot. What would be more convenient than his bibliographies, with short explanations of what each paper has done? If I were you, and I was set on working on the problem, I would decide which of the papers were related to the methods I had in mind, or which ones at least sound interesting.

But to be sure, he was two bibliographies. Pre 2000 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf) and 2000-2009 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608208v6.pdf). As mentioned in the comments, he has a [book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11057820-a-mathematical-challenge), and an [intro](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-78-prev.pdf). Lagarias is the expert, and there's no better list.

I would also mention that the problem is unsolved, and so I recommend patience. Developing the patience to read a beautifully written set of annotated bibliographies might be a good place to start.