# What level of mathematics do I need to study the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I recently came across the Collatz Conjecture and I'm really intrigued by its tautological simplicity and complexity.

I'm under no illusions that I can make any progress with a proof for it but I really want to study it more and be able to understand attempts at proofs.

I've studied maths to A2 level (albeit a few years ago now), so any advice as to how much more I'd need to study, in particular what areas? Any tips as to where I could learn more and the best way to go about it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This should answer it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176937/prerequisite-reading-before-studying-the-collatz-3x1-problem

Comment: I remember when I first heard of the collatz-conjecture. I tried to prove it, but gave up after a short time and thought to myself : Surely, this problem has been solved ! I had no idea how difficult, perhaps impossible it is to proof a claim that is so easy to understand. The situation is somewhat worse than it is for Goldbach's conjecture. There is not even a statistical evidence for the truth of the conjecture.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look through the posts!

Comment: Perhaps you'll like that essay of mine, which does involve only amateurish math, but collects a fair number of courious observations: http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of this problem is that it can be *studied* with any level of mathematics.  Solving it however, is a different matter.

The fact that so many have tried and failed proves the following:

If proof with elementary mathematics is possible, then it requires some exceptional feat of logic, reasoning, or intuition, which has eluded so many people before.

If proof with more difficult mathematics already in existence is possible, then it still probably requires some exceptional feat of logic, reasoning, or intuition, which has eluded so many people before.

However... I think it was Erdos who said, he didn't believe the mathematics to solve this problem yet exists.

There are many methods which can be used to tackle this problem.  A proof is more likely to come out of an advanced field of number theory, such as the p-adics and modular elliptic curves.

If however there is some field of relatively elementary mathematics you wanted to study, which is more likely to yield a result, it is the field of modular arithmetic, because the problem derives its complexity out of the moire that arises out of mod 2 and mod 3 arithmetic.

Comment: The elliptic curves where the key to solve Fermat's last theorem. But in the case of the Collatz-conjecture, I am very spectical, that this will help because the behaviour of a trajectory in the Collatz-sequence is chaotic and almost unpredictable (in the sense that there is probably no shortcut to verify more efficiently whether a sequence terminates than basically brute force). Apparently, in the case of Fermat's last theorem, a useful hidden structure allowed the proof, but such a structure is unlikely in the case of the Collatz-conjecture.

Comment: The only progress that was made was to rule out longer and longer possible cycles. But even if we can prove that no non-trivial cycle exists, the Collatz-conjecture still is far from being proven. All this indicates that Erdoes is right by saying that mathematics is not ready yet for such problems.

Comment: @Peter a full discussion is beyond the scope of the comments here & you declined the offer to discuss this in more depth before, but the chaotic trajectories are very easily eliminated or made sense of, by the study of a certain slightly modified graph over $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ or $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ whose convergence is equivalent to the original problem. Sadly it's a slow process for me to acquire the maths skills. The offer is still there but your profile says you're interested in large numbers. I suspect you're more interested in finding a very large counterexample than proving the conjecture!

Comment: I am interested in large numbers, yes, but I do not concentrate on proving famous open conjectures like the collatz conjecture. Just because I do not see a realistic chance that it can work (and if, I am pretty sure that I am not the lucky one who will solve the conjecture). I am also honest that I do not understand the structure of the collatz-tree , maybe some users understand it better. I cannot claim that the tree cannot solve the conjecture, but what I think that such approaches have already been tried. So, it is not lack of interest in the problem.

Comment: Did you ask other users whether they can help you ? I am honest enough to myself that I do not think that I am the smartest mathemtician on this site, even less concerning the collatz-conjecture. Moreover, my personal belief is that the collatz conjecture won't be cracked in near future - of course this is only a belief. I might be wrong. But I would be very surprised if this problem will actually be cracked.

Comment: I can open a chatroom for the collatz-conjecture (if not already one exists) , but I will rather follow the chat with much interest than actively take part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82275/discussion-between-peter-and-robert-frost).